# Scale Image Size in Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, png

I am receiving a base64 image from an api that is 192x192 in size. I am using the following code to change the base64 data into a Bitmap.

```
    fun Base64ToBitmap(myImageData: String): Bitmap {
    val imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(myImageData.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.size)
}
```

Then I am using the following code to replace the previous contents of my ImageView.

```
ImageHeader.setImageBitmap(img)
```

The xml for that ImageHeader are as follows.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ImageHeader1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_home"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/defaultpng" />
```

As expected this makes a very small image on the app. Is there anyway I can scale it's size x2 or x4 without having to create a larger image from my base php api? Sending extra data over the API seems like a waste.

Comment: check out this function >>> private Drawable resizeDrawable(Drawable drawable, int dstWidth, int dstHeight) {
Drawable resizedDrawable = null;
try {
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, false);
resizedDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmapResized).mutate();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
resizedDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
        return resizedDrawable;}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Glide` to resize your bitmap, see below

```
 Glide.with(requireActivity())
                .override(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE)
                .load(yourBitmap)
                .into(yourImageView)
```